# If $g:[a,b]\to[0,\infty]$ is lebesgue integrable on the compact interval $[a,b]$, is $g$ bounded $\textit{almost everywhere}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know that $g\in L^1[a,b]$ implies that $g<\infty$ almost everywhere. It seems like it should follow that $g$ is bounded almost everywhere, but I can't think of a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: What about $g(x) = x^{-1/2}$ on $(0, 1)$?

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313919/42969.

Comment: What does $g$ bounded a.e. mean?

Comment: @zhw I was thinking in the sense that there is some real number $M$ such that $|g|\leq M$ everywhere on $[a,b]$ except possibly on a subset of measure zero.

Comment: The way to say that is $g\in L^\infty.$